# Android: Best way to save image at external Storage

Tags: android, external

When i'm trying to save an image at some devices the app crashes.
After some research i think the problem is the imageRoot, but i'm kind of lost with so many solutions...
I think the problem is about obtaining external storage path.
The device i'm using to test my app doesn't have any  sd card, the path is `/mnt/sdcard/Pictures` and the image is being saved successfully.
I want it to work whether phone has an sd card or not.
Thanks for any help in advance.

```
imageRoot=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "AppName");

private void saveImage() {


        Bitmap bitmap = sqimage.getDrawingCache();
        File image = new File(imageRoot, imageName);



        if (image.exists()) {
            image.delete();

        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(image);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            new SingleMediaFileConnector(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), image);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            success = false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            success = false;
        }
  }
```

Comment: i don't have logs when the app crashes because it isn't my device and the application is being installed with the .apk without android studio.

Comment: You can get the logs using adb command. Use `abd logcat -d > FileName.txt` to push logs of crash to txt file

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` path doesn't exist. You need to check for its existence.

```
try {
    imageRoot=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "AppName");
    File image = new File(imageRoot, imageName);

    // Make sure the Pictures directory exists.
    imageRoot.mkdirs();

    // Other stuffs here

} catch (IOException e) {
    // Unable to create file, likely because external storage is
    // not currently mounted.
    Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + file, e);
}
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) for more details.

**[Edit]**
An alternate way can be use:

```
getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

Comment: i do the proper check if the path exists.
if(!imageRoot.exists()){imageRoot.mkdirs();}

Comment: Your app may crash at the time creating `imageRoot`. Put it inside try catch block and check if you get an exception there